# How to select distinct rows from table without using functions(min,max etc)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have seen a lot of questions about this lately but I think that there should be something easier than to `Group By` by one column and making all the other fields of the selected table as `Min`, `Max`, `Average` functions. For example I have a big table with 20 columns. I don't think making 19 columns as functions is the right choice.

I have tried `Distinct` but it gives also duplicate values. 
Also putting every field of the select in the `Group By` doesn't work either because Oracle complains:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Any idea?

Comment: What values are showing duplicates with DISTINCT? Only particular data types? GROUP_BY has a particular meaning and isn't meant to be used in this way

Comment: can you provide more info on what you aim at? standard procedure would be to use a grouped result set in a subquery relieving you from the necessity of aggregating all other columns for the sake of syntax conformance

Comment: I want to select all the distinct rows, that have one value distinct for example CustomerNum, There are some rows that have same CustomerNum. The column values are Int,Varchar,Date etc. The CustomerNum column has Number type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select distinct rows using the `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by <columns that should be different>
                                order by NULL) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir :) However I think they should include some command or something like that to perform this task as it is very required in everyday job.